# Create any file with Razor

Tags: razor

Can I create not `.cshtml` file (`.txt`, `.js` ...), include Razor operators in it and parse in runtime using Razor engine (in web or desktop .NET application)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, just take a look at the [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) on codeplex. Razor is just a templating engine that could be used in any application including console, desktop, ... and it is not tightly coupled coupled to an `HttpContext` like the WebForms *pseudo* view engine.